# How to create complex shortcut keys for windows application

Tags: c#, hotkeys, windows

I know how to implement <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>A</kbd> or <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>k</kbd> shortcut in Windows form. But as this application as lots of Module, I want to create Complex/Fancy shortcuts like <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd>,<kbd>A</kbd> or <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd>,<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>A</kbd> which opens up Specific one module. Is it possible to do? if so, How can I do it?

I tried to google, but couldn't able to do it. I found <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd>,<kbd>A</kbd> alike shortcuts in Visual Studio, e.g. <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>K</kbd>, <kbd>S</kbd>. When Pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>K</kbd>, status bar is saying : "<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>K</kbd> was pressed, waiting for second key of chord.." and then pressing <kbd>S</kbd>, it's showing "The key combination <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>K</kbd>, <kbd>S</kbd> is bound to....."

Is it possible to do for normal windows application? if not, what other method I can use?

Comment: Have you seen [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/192055/how-do-i-create-compound-keyboard-shortcuts-in-a-winforms-application)?

Comment: @IswantoSan Thanks, I haven't seen it. I'll have a read.