# Creating short cut keys with multiple chars(ALt+DE) in windows form application using C#

Tags: c#

I want to design a short cut keys framework in windows form application using C#. Such as *"Alt + DE"* such that the second short cut key option is a combination of multiple characters. Is there any way to achieve this.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I create compound keyboard shortcuts in a Windows Forms application?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/192055/how-do-i-create-compound-keyboard-shortcuts-in-a-windows-forms-application)

Answer (score 0):

MSDN:

> https://support.microsoft.com/en-gb/kb/839201

Example Code:

```
private void Form1_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Alt && e.KeyCode.ToString() == "F")
    {
        // When the user presses both the 'Alt' key and 'F' key,
        // KeyPreview is set to False, and a message appears.
        // This message is only displayed when KeyPreview is set to True.
        this.KeyPreview = true;
        MessageBox.Show("KeyPreview is True, and this is from the FORM.");
    } 
}
```